# can not change variable inside handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem with setting state.

I have 2 handle methods declared on the same place. 1.work 2. print output but does not set state.

Handlers are called inside render method.

How to set state in 2nd handler?

```
//handle definitions are on the same place
//this works
handleOpenOptions(){
    this.setState({
        showOptions: true,
        menuOpened: false
    });
}
//This print into console "test" but does not set showOptions: false
handleCloseOptions(){
    console.log("test")
    this.setState({
        showOptions: false
    })
}

//calling functions inside render method
<Collapse in={this.state.options} 
    timeout="auto"
    unmountOnExit>
    <List 
        component="div" 
        disablePadding>
        <ListItem style={listStyle2} button>
            <ListItemText 
                disableTypography 
                inset 
                primary={intl.get('MENUSERVERCONNECTION')} />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem 
            style={listStyle2} 
            button 
            onClick={this.handleOpenOptions.bind(this)}>

            <ListItemText 
                disableTypography 
                inset 
                primary={intl.get('MENUOPTIONS2')} />
            <ReactModal className="modal"
                isOpen={this.state.showOptions}
                ariaHideApp={false}
                contentLabel="Minimal Modal">

                <MuiThemeProvider>
                    <div>
                        <AppBar title={intl.get('MODALOPTIONS')} />
                        <ul>
                            <li><p>American style date format</p></li>
                        </ul>
                        <Button className="modalClose" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.handleCloseOptions.bind(this)}>{intl.get('BUTTCLOSEMODALEXTRAORDINARYEXPEDITION')} </Button>
                    </div>
                </MuiThemeProvider>
            </ReactModal>
        </ListItem>
    </List>
</Collapse>
```

Comment: Could you try tidying up your code indenting, it's hurting my eyes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the `Button`, you click also on the `ListItem`, so `handleCloseOptions` is call then `handleOpenOptions` is call. ([see here for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events))

To prevent that, your `handleCloseOptions` should be :

```
handleCloseOptions(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("test")
    this.setState({
        showOptions: false
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**USE ARROW FUNCTIONS**

Try changing your close handler to:

```
handleCloseOptions = () => {
    console.log("test")
    this.setState({
        showOptions: false
    })
}
```

Comment: Doesn't set state.